# How to write a SQL so that it can be run on any database

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

I have to write an application (in server 1) that will generate a SQL. The SQL will be transferred to some different server (server 2). Another application which is deployed on server 2 will run the query on a database deployed in server 2.

Now there can be different types of database and the query will not be a simple one (may be 200 lines of query). Is there any third party application (like Hibernate) which I can use to create the query may be in a different format (like HQL), which can be transferred to server 2 and the application on server 2 will convert it to a DB specific SQL and run it?

I am using Spring & Java 8 to write the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are many JPA providers including hibernate, what is that different are you looking for?

Comment: The SQL generator and the SQl executer are deployed on two different servers. Can I use hibernate here? Also can I write complex queries in HQL in hibernate? @secretsuperstar

Comment: yes. IMHO, but when you say complex query, but it is abstract. but without knowing what query you would like write, it is next to impossible to say if something can't be done or not. For example,  I highly doubt if `with` clause can be used in `hql`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for native sql query. But If you use any ORM technology like Hibernate then it is possible. Hibernate dialect will generate different database specific query for you. Though hibernate is an ORM technology it will defines relations with Objects that will represent your database table's. Popularly we call that objects as Entity. SO If you want to use different database then there will be no problem. But you have to change dialect for different databases.

Comment: The SQL generator and the SQl executer are deployed on two different servers. Can I use hibernate here? Also can I write complex queries in HQL in hibernate? @flopcoder

Comment: Sure you can write query in HQL

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ORM - JPA or Hibernate and move queries to configurable different XML which works for each platform/DB? Deploy the XML based on DB...

No shortcut here but if you use ANSI SQL standards which is a platform-independent and is used as a base with most Database systems including  Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, IBM DB2 etc you queries should work almost without any issues. Obviously you will loose on added features of DB's provide.